# If V is a real vector space, how does it have the same dimension as it's complexification?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am reading LADR by Axler. His $9.4$ theorem states that if $V$ is a vector space, it has the same dimension as $V_{\Bbb C}$, which is the complexification of $V$. But Axler defines the complexification of $V$ as equal to $V\times V$, which has elements of ordered pairs $(u,v)$ where we write it as $u + iv$, with the usual addition and multiplication of complex vector spaces.

But from an earlier chapter, Axler says the dimension of $V\times W$ is equal to the dimension of $V$ plus the dimension of $W$.

So since $V_{\Bbb C} = V\times V$, shouldnt the dimension of $V_{\Bbb C} =$ twice the dimension of $V$?

Comment: The two share a basis...but the field of scalars has changed.  The new space is defined over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I suspect Axler said the (real) dimension of $V$ was the same as the *complex* dimension of $V^{\Bbb C}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes you are correct. but my question goes a bit further. Lets say you have a real 1 dimensional vector space V. and v1 is a basis of V. The complexification Vc =  VxV, can have 1 + 0i as a vector, and 0 + i as a vector. Doesn't this make the dimension of Vc two?

Comment: @scool89 Note that $0+1i$ **is** a scalar multiple of $1+0i$ if our scalars are from $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$. The *real* dimension of the complexification is twice that of the real dimension of the original space, but the *complex* dimension of the complexification is the same as the real dimension of the original space.

Comment: @noahschweber thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 4):

The dimension of a vector space depends on which field you are viewing it as a vector space over! If $V$ is a real vector space, then its complexification is $V_{\mathbb C}:=\mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb R} V$, which because $\mathbb C$ has $\mathbb R$-basis $\{1,i\}$ is equivalent as an $\mathbb R$-vector space, to $V\times V$, but where the second copy of $V$ is viewed as $iV$, so if, for example, $B=\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ was a basis of $V$ over $\mathbb R$, then $B_{\mathbb R}=\{e_1,\ldots,e_n,ie_1,\ldots,ie_n\}$ is a basis of $V_{\mathbb C}$, its complexification, over $\mathbb R$, while $B$ is a basis for $V_{\mathbb C}$ over $\mathbb C$: if $\{a_j,b_j: 1\leq j\leq n\}$ are real numbers then
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n a_je_j+ \sum_{j=1}^n b_jie_j = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_j e_j,
$$
where $\lambda_j = a_j+ib_j$, so $B$ spans $V_{\mathbb C}$ over $\mathbb C$, while $B_\mathbb R$ spans $V_{\mathbb C}$ over $\mathbb R$, and similarly $B_{\mathbb R}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb R$, but becomes linearly dependent over $\mathbb C$.